# Elementary question about changing the sign of an integration variable

Tags: integration

In the middle of a physics calculation, after applying Fourier's transform, I have obtained an integral of the form:

$$\int C_{\vec{k}} e^{i(\omega t+\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x})}d^3k$$

where $C_{\vec{k}}$ is a complex number that depends on $\vec{k}$. The book claims we can change $\vec{k}$ to $-\vec{k}$. Why? I see no way to justify this step, as the integrand changes when we do this.

Comment: Yes, things must change accordingly. Is it claimed that they do not? Can you quote what exactly they claim?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes, as an explanation the book just says "we have sent $\vec{k}$ to $-\vec{k}$ in the last line" after claiming that:

$$\int C_\vec{k}\cdot e^{i(\omega_k t+\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x})}d^3k=\int C_{-\vec{k}}\cdot e^{i(\omega_k t-\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x})}d^3k$$

I was wondering if it is implied that we are integating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, but I think it's not, and anyway I don't think that would change anything...

Comment: Ok that equal sign is perfectly fine. They’re integrating over all of $R^3$. Also note there is no extra minus sign because the determinant of this change of variables has **absolute value** +1. You should take another look at what the change of variables theorem states.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Oh, I see! The determinant of the change of variables would be the determinant of minus the identity matrix $I_{3\times 3}$, right? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes so in odd dimensions (like 3) it is $-1$, and in even dimensions it is $1$, in either case absolute value is $1$.